# Implement an IEnumerable include async/await Task

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I want create a container that every-time i want get its items (iterate), it **return the item to me with a delay**. *Really i want impleament multiple kinde of delays (delay with timer + delay after return each item + delay after return some items).*

But I simplify the idea in the following example. **The following code works but** it has a problem when i use `await Task.Delay(...)`. I describe it in the code (please read comments).

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to implement it with a `GetEnumerator` method as *prevent* blocking of the thread that iterate the `MyContainer object`?
- What is your interesting ways to realize this idea (any Interesting solution)? : )

> I think it is clear that i want hide and embed delay mechanism in `IEnumerable<T>`.
>
> I wont make a simple `foreach` over a `List<int>` include delay in the body of my high level class.
>
> I want make a container with an embed delay mechanism and finally just use a `foreach` over `MyContainer` without any delay in it (like bellow test).

```
class MyContainer : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private readonly int _sec;
    private readonly List<int> _items;
    public MyContainer(List<int> items, int sec)
    {
        this._sec = sec;
        this._items = items;
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _items.Count(); ++i)
        {
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------
            // It works but block caller thread (E.g. block UI Thread)
            Thread.Sleep(Sec*1000);

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------
            //Problem line:
            //Because return type of current method should be async Task<...>
            //And it seems «yield» has problem with Task methods
            //await Task.Delay(_sec*1000); // <<<  Error line

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------
            yield return _items[i];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

**Test** of above code with `Thread.Sleep` (without `await Task.Delay`):

```
var myCnt=new MyContainer(new List<int>() {10,20,30,40,50}, 2);
var sw=new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

foreach (var item in myCnt)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}

sw.Stop();

// Result:
// 00:00:02.0014343
// 00:00:04.0034690
// 00:00:06.0045362
// 00:00:08.0056571
// 00:00:10.0067891
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. You want your iterator to include a delay, but you don't want `foreach` to be delayed? It sounds like maybe the delays/timers you need should be implemented at a different part of the stack.

Comment: BTW, It's easier to mix async/await and enumerables if you use an implementation of `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, such as: https://github.com/tyrotoxin/AsyncEnumerable

Comment: @NateBarbettini, your `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` link is interesting! May you write your comment with an example of it as an answer here? I think it will help others in the future in this question page if they want mix `IEnumerable<T>` and `Task`s like me.
Link:
_Helps to (a) create an element provider, where producing an element can take a lot of time due to dependency on other asynchronous events (e.g. wait handles, network streams),
(b) a consumer that processes those element as soon as they are ready without blocking the thread (the processing is scheduled on a worker thread instead)._

Answer (score 0):

This ought to get you most of the way conceptually, and you can tweak it.

The idea is that it isn't blocking, but each of the yielded values can be awaited with a controllable delay.

```
public static IEnumerable<Task<T>> EnumerateWithDelay<T>(Func<int, T> generator, Func<int, T, bool> limiter, TimeSpan delay)
{
    var idx = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var item = generator(idx);
        if (!limiter(idx, item)) yield break;
        yield return Task.Delay(delay).ContinueWith(_ => item);
        idx++;
    }
}

public async Task A()
{
    foreach (var itemTask in EnumerateWithDelay(idx => idx, (idx, val) => idx < 10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)))
    {
        // I'll take .5 seconds
        var number = await itemTask;
    }
}
```

With a bit of tweaking you could make the generator function not be called until after the delay was up.